# How can I draw a grouped bar plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I have computed the precision, recall and f measure for the algorithm. I want to draw bar plot for the three values. Precision = 1*256, recall = 1*256, F-measure = 1*256.

I am getting a figure like this:

[image: Image result]

But, I want to draw bar plot like this:

[image: Expected image]

I am very new to Matlab programming and I have tried this following code

```
data = [P_1,R_1,f_1
    P_2,R_2,f_2
    P_3,R_3,f_3
    P_4,R_4,f_4];
b=bar(data);
set(b,{'FaceColor'},{'b';'r';'y'});
grid on;
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'DEMO1','DEMO2','DEMO3','DEMO4'});
legend('Precision','Recall','F_\beta');
```

please help me to solve this.

I am attaching the [text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpxhmo7rh5waj70/F1.txt?dl=0) which consists of P1, R1 and F1.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:
we have in total 12 vectors of 256 values, but we have to calculate the mean or median or any value. In the end, you have to compute only one value from P1 to P_1.Thank you so much @EBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but you have 2 mistakes.

1. You build `data` from the whole vector of *Precision* (P1, P2...) and the other measurements, while with `bar` you only input the value to be plotted. All the values that `bar` plots are scalars [like here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html?s_tid=doc_ta#bug9u7m-1), so **you** have to do all the statistics before using `bar` for plotting. In your case, I believe you want to take the average of each of your variables, so `P_1 = mean(P1)` and `R_1 = mean(R1)` etc. for all of your variables. Eventually, you will get 12 scalars from you 12 vectors.
2. Then, you need to arrange correctly that values in a matrix. Each row stands for a group and each column stands for a color. Basically, you did something close but messed up the commas and line brakes.

All you need to do is to build `data` correctly (when all the variables within it are scalars):

```
data = [P_1 R_1 f_1
    P_2 R_2 f_2
    P_3 R_3 f_3
    P_4 R_4 f_4];
```

Notice that I removed all commas, because in Matlab you either specify with `,` and `;` the shape of the matrix, or you use spaces and line-breaks. [If you mix both you get in trouble](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-84906)...

So `data` is 4-by-3, each row is a demo and each column is a measure. With some random data it looks like this:

```
data = rand(4,3);
b = bar(data);
set(b,{'FaceColor'},{'b';'r';'y'});
grid on;
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'DEMO1','DEMO2','DEMO3','DEMO4'});
legend('Precision','Recall','F_\beta');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I am stilling the old bar plot.I have attached the text file which consists of p1,r1,f1 values

Comment: @Azaad I can't see the file(the link doesn't work), but this should be no more than 12 values, you can just type them in the question.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier p1,r1,f1 contains 1*256 values. I have attached the text file. please click on the textfile link

Comment: @Azaad OK, so you have in total 12 vectors of 256 values, but what do you want to see in the bar plot? Their mean? Their maximum value? Another statistic? In the end, you _have to_ compute only one value from P1 to `P_1`

Comment: @Azaad see my edit to the answer, hop it clarify things for you.

Comment: @EBH.Thank you so much. I got it